# Circuit symbol for ammeter with output

Tags: schematics

What is the correct symbol for an ammeter that measures 0..200 mA and generates 0..2 V proportional output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the same as a current controlled voltage source, a CCVS. The symbol looks [like a diamond](http://www.google.com/imgres?hl=en&tbo=d&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS448US448&biw=1920&bih=912&tbm=isch&tbnid=BRW_rQVLX7PhQM%3a&imgrefurl=http://wiki.msoe.us/ee2050/circuitbasics&docid=QVaX1Cevh0d3aM&imgurl=http://wiki.msoe.us/_media/ee2050/2050depvs.png&w=68&h=85&ei=Dg6fUKG5OuH5igKbmIDIBQ&zoom=1&iact=rc&dur=343&sig=111285970762716931368&page=1&tbnh=80&tbnw=64&start=0&ndsp=48&ved=1t:429,r:7,s:0,i:95&tx=29&ty=32) with an equation next to it. In your case, V=10A.

Answer (score 3):

We don't normally call that an *ammeter*, but a *current-controlled voltage source*. One common symbol is this (courtesy of [Wikimedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Voltage_Source_%28Controlled%29.svg)):

[image]

Text next to the symbol should indicate how it's controlled. For example, "\$I_1\times{}10\Omega\$".

If you want to represent a physical device that has this function, you'd probably just use a rectangular box with pins corresponding to each of the physical pins.